# How to change return value of mocked class method

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a mocked class of a node module and its method as below, and test case to test case I need to change the `methodOne` returning value.

````
jest.mock("module_name", () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    Abc: class Abc {
      constructor(config) {}

      async methodOne(params) {
        return {
          message: {
            content:
              'This text I need to change',
          },
        };
      }
    },
    Configuration: class Configuration {
      constructor(config) {
        return true;
      }
    },
  };
});

describe("getVeganStatus", () => {
  it("should handle case one......", async () => {
    // methodOne message.content return value should be "ABC"
  })

  it("should handle case two......", async () => {
    // methodOne message.content return value should be "XYZ"
  });
})```
````

Answer (score 1):

Following [Replacing the mock using `mockImplementation()` or `mockImplementationOnce()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#replacing-the-mock-using-mockimplementation-or-mockimplementationonce) documentation.

> Calls to `jest.mock` are hoisted to the top of the code. You can specify a mock later, e.g. in `beforeAll()`, by calling `mockImplementation()` (or `mockImplementationOnce()`) on the existing mock instead of using the factory parameter. **This also allows you to change the mock between tests, if needed**:

E.g.

`some-module.js`:

```js
export class Abc {
  constructor(config) {}

  async methodOne(params) {
    return {
      message: {
        content:
          'This text I need to change',
      },
    };
  }
}
```

`main.js`:

```js
import { Abc } from './some-module';

export async function main() {
    const abc = new Abc();
    return abc.methodOne().then((res) => res.message.content);
}
```

`main.test.js`:

```js
import { main } from './main';
import { Abc } from './some-module';

jest.mock('./some-module');

describe('76863882', () => {
    test('should pass 1', async () => {
        Abc.mockImplementation(() => {
            return {
                methodOne: async () => ({ message: { content: 'ABC' } }),
            };
        });
        const actual = await main();
        expect(actual).toBe('ABC');
    });

    test('should pass 2', async () => {
        Abc.mockImplementation(() => {
            return {
                methodOne: async () => ({ message: { content: 'XYZ' } }),
            };
        });
        const actual = await main();
        expect(actual).toBe('XYZ');
    });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76863882/main.test.js (5.787 s)
  76863882
    ✓ should pass 1 (2 ms)
    ✓ should pass 2

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.978 s, estimated 6 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```